# OpenCL lost value of variables because of for-loop

Tags: for-loop, opencl

I've the following opencl-code:

```
__constant SomeConstants[] = { 5, 7, 242, 74 };

long aslong(__global int * arr, int offset) {
    return ... <CalculateLong> ...;
};

void calcSomething(__global int * numArray, int * result) {
    long tempArray[] = { numArray[0], numArray[1], numArray[2], numArray[3] };

    long x0 = (result[0] = aslong(numArray, 0)) + tempArray[0];
    long x1 = (result[1] = aslong(numArray, 8)) + tempArray[1];
    long x2 = (result[2] = aslong(numArray, 16)) + tempArray[2];
    long x3 = (result[3] = aslong(numArray, 32)) + tempArray[3];
    // do some calculations here
    result[0] = x0;
    result[1] = x1;
    result[2] = x2;
    result[3] = x3;

};

__kernel void calc(__global int * numArray, __global long * sum) {
    long arr[] = { SomeConstants[0], SomeConstants[1], SomeConstants[2], SomeConstants[3] };
    calcSomething(numArray, arr);
    sum[get_global_id(0)] = arr[0];
    sum[get_global_id(0)+1] = arr[1];
    sum[get_global_id(0)+2] = arr[2];
    sum[get_global_id(0)+3] = arr[3];
};
```

The code above works as expected but the problem is, that I can't add some more calculations to calcSomething. When I add an empty loop to calcSomethig like as follows:

```
void calcSomething(__global int * numArray, int * result) {
    long tempArray[] = { numArray[0], numArray[1], numArray[2], numArray[3] };

    long x0 = (result[0] = aslong(numArray, 0)) + tempArray[0];
    long x1 = (result[1] = aslong(numArray, 8)) + tempArray[1];
    long x2 = (result[2] = aslong(numArray, 16)) + tempArray[2];
    long x3 = (result[3] = aslong(numArray, 32)) + tempArray[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {}

    result[0] = x0;
    result[1] = x1;
    result[2] = x2;
    result[3] = x3;

};
```

result[0] and result[1] stores the correct values, but result[2] and result[3] are absolutely wrong. By commenting out the for-loop, result[2] and 3 are correct... any idea what happened to x0, x1, x2 and x3 while calling the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER:** Your problem is located in the operations:

```
sum[get_global_id(0)] = arr[0];
sum[get_global_id(0)+1] = arr[1];
sum[get_global_id(0)+2] = arr[2];
sum[get_global_id(0)+3] = arr[3];
```

You are using your `sum[]` global array with overlapping indexes. However **MANY** work-items will write the same memory, producing undefined results.
You need either to fix the overlapping, or perform an atomic operation to the global variable.

Example:

```
 gid 0 -> Write to sum[0,1,2,3]
 gid 1 -> Write to sum[1,2,3,4]
 //....
```

The `for` loop doesn't have to do with the problem at all. You are just seeing the effect of different schedules in a multithreaded enviroment. But that is not the root of the problem.

**Further edit:**
The code has problems NOT related to OpenCL. The only problem with OpenCL is already described above.

There are many places where C variables are wrongly adressed or casted implicitly and then used wrongly. For example in `aslong()` 8 consecutive ints are added to make a long, but a long is made of 8bytes, not 8int.

Comment: You mean, I've to use get_global_id(0) instead of access the array with absolute indexes? My result-array isn't defined as __global. I'm creating the result-array in my calc-Kernel...

Comment: Sry, the answer is valid but the variables are wrong. Let me edit it.

Comment: Alright, thanks, but I've only 1 work item (for testing purposes). That's the reason for absolute indexes... it is also notable that the result is **always** correct without the loop. When I add the for loop, the last 2 results are **always** wrong (but **always** have the same value).

Comment: Mmm, are you sure you are running 1 work-item only? Does your global aray have enough space for 4 long values?

Comment: Yes... the global sum-array in my kernel has space for 8 long values (for testing purposes). Edit:\\ The same problem occurs when I try to replace the for loop with a while loop...

Comment: I just reallized you have some times `int` and some times `long` as your parameters. In OpenCL `int` is fixed to be a 32bits integer, and `long` a 64bits one. While `short` in only 16bits. Unlike C/C++. Check that in your code and check again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41022/discussion-between-darkzeros-and-nrgyzer)

Comment: I changed everything to long but this didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Please post all your code if you can, since it is unlikely that the problem is in the for loop, and the code looks OK to me.

Comment: I just know why the results are wrong: Because asLong sometimes returns 0, but only when I add a loop (this could also be an empty loop like above).

Comment: That's the code of asLong: return (((arr[offset] & 255) + ((arr[offset + 1] & 255) << 8) + ((arr[offset + 2] & 255) << 16) + ((arr[offset + 3] & 255) << 24)) & 0xffffffffL) + (((arr[offset + 4] & 255) + ((arr[offset + 5] & 255) << 8) + ((arr[offset + 6] & 255) << 16) + ((arr[offset + 7] & 255L) << 24)) << 32);

Comment: I just replaced the method and doing this with a loop which seems to work - but I'm still absolutely confused why it doesn't work with method call

Comment: Your code is poorly written. This is no longer an OpenCL problem, but a C/C++/General programming problem.
So please fix your errors (3 or more already) and then post a specific problem. So far: work-items global writes overlap, variables long/short/int mixup, wrong array adressing(cast a long pointer as int, then adress it like an int value), not using clWriteBuffer to copy data first to GPU, ....